# Given repeating sections, how do I find sections matching certain criteria using Powershell

Tags: parsing, powershell

I need to parse a text file and retrieve data from it... based on other data in the same file..

I need to find the lines that say not ok.. and then find the Nodes they are under.. 
I know how to pull the data in..and find the Not Ok's and the Nodes.  I also have an idea that I'm sure is overly complicated to find what I'm looking for.  I can parse the Node lines into an array so like

```
$test = (select-string -path C:\error.txt -Pattern "Node:").linenumber
```

then find the line number of the not oks and backup lol but this seems like the most difficult way to do this.  I'm familiar with PS but not an expert.

```
$test2 = (select-string -path C:\error.txt -Pattern "Not ok").linenumber
```

so to spell out what I need ..

parse file for Node.. find lines below that are not ok.. and if so set node to variable...if not ok isn't found move on to next node.

Thanks for any help

example txt file below

```
Node: Server
*********************

Line 1 ok
line 2 ok 
line 3 ok
Line 4 Not ok
line 5 ok
line 6 ok
*********************

Node: Server2
*********************
Line 1 ok
line 2 ok 
line 3 Not ok
Line 4 ok
line 5 ok
line 6 ok
*********************
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```powershell
$errorNodes = @()

Get-Content C:\temp\test.txt | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -imatch 'Node: (.+)$') {
        $node = $Matches[1]
    } 
    if ($_ -imatch 'not ok') {
        $errorNodes += $node
    }
}

$errorNodes
```

### Explanation

1. `Get-Content` reads a file line by line.
2. For each line, first check to see if it's a node; if so, set the `$node` variable to the current node's name.
3. Then check to see if the line matches the text 'not ok'. If so, add the node name to the list of error nodes (the array variable `$errorNodes`.

So at the end, `$errorNodes` will contain the nodes with problems.

Comment: No need for `?` in regex match

Comment: True. You might say the `?` is optional.

Comment: Ha, touche.  I was assuming there'd always be a server name :)

Comment: Joking aside, I removed it because I think it would technically perform worse since a greedy `+` wouldn't have to backtrack in this case, while a non-greedy would.

Comment: So the (.+)$ ( I suck at regex ) is saying match any single characters any number of times.. until the end of the line and give me that which is after Node:.... Correct?  I've also added a on bit to it..to allow for more than 1 not ok

if ($_ -imatch "not ok") {
        if ( $errorNodes -inotcontains $node ) {
        $errorNodes += $node
        }
    }

Comment: `(.+)$` is saying match 1 or more of any character (and capture for later retrieval), followed by the end of string. The parentheses are what allow `$Matches[1]` to retrieve it later.

Comment: @DanielPeel http://regexpal.com/ (there's several of these out there- always handy)

Comment: Thanks.. since this is my first post.. I can't up vote.. or I would.

Comment: It's late.. and not much.. lol but I up voted this.. since I can!

Comment: @DanielPeel no problem, I upvoted the question as well (which I should have way back then, but I was new and at the time as well). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your list is long, this should be a quicker way to parse (also less code :)):

```
$nodes = [Regex]::Split((Get-Content info.txt), 'Node:')
# '?' is an alias for Where-Object
$bad = $nodes | ? { $_.ToLower().Contains('not ok') }
```

`$bad` now also contains all the text under the node containing "not ok" (in the even there are multiple lines that are not ok).

Comment: That is very cool...and offers me a new way to look at data.. however, this as you say gives me everything and I would only want the server name.  Thanks for the option:)

Comment: oops - i interpreted "set node to variable" as "assign all the values/content under that node to a variable" (again assuming you'd want to know which items were 'not ok').  My b- good luck!

Comment: Ya the goal of this is to run a script that tests given servers for agents running on them... based on "any" agent not running... will give me the node.. and allow me to take that node and run a command that restarts the agents.  So 1 or all agents needs only the same reply.. server name.  Then I can pass that into a new foreach that will restart the agents... I will create structure that will retest to verify they started. :) and no worries.. I'm just appreciative of the help given by all :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is most likely more complicated than it needs to be but it returns useful objects that, depending what else op needs to do in his code, can be useful for further processing. For this example I used the file structure of the OP and added some extra nodes to make the output a little more verbose.

```
$file = Get-Content "c:\temp\test.txt" -Raw
$file -split '\s+(?=Node: \w+)' | 
        %{ $stringData = (($_ -replace ": "," = ") -replace 'line\W+(\d+)\W+','Line$1 = ') -replace '\*+' 
                New-Object PSObject -Property  $(ConvertFrom-StringData $Stringdata)
        } | select node,line* | Format-Table
```

Using PowerShell 3.0: The code will read the file as a whole string (Not creating a string array) using the `-Raw` parameter. The `$file` is the string split at the text "Node: " which will break up the Nodes as separate objects.

In order to create the custom object we need to make sure all the items of the Node contain name=value pairs. To accomplish this I nested some `-replace` operations.

1. `$_ -replace ": "," = "` - To change the first line to "Node = Servername"
2. `-replace 'line\W+(\d+)\W+','Line$1 = '` - Convert `Line # ok` into `Line# = Ok\Not Ok` Where # is the particular line 1-6
3. `-replace '\*+'` - To remove the lines that contain just astericks ( or whatever the plural of astericks is)

The formated string is used as input for `New-Object PSObject -Property  $(ConvertFrom-StringData $Stringdata)`

After that we can control the piped output like we would almost any other object. To ensure that node appears first in the list the `select-object` statement.

The following is my sample output:

```
Node                     Line4                    Line5                   Line6                   Line1                   Line2                   Line3                  
----                     -----                    -----                   -----                   -----                   -----                   -----                  
Server                   Not ok                   ok                      ok                      ok                      ok                      ok                     
Server2                  ok                       ok                      ok                      ok                      ok                      Not ok                 
Server4                  ok                       ok                      ok                      Not ok                  ok                      ok                     
Server3                  ok                       ok                      ok                      ok                      ok                      ok
```

Comment: Wow... if I wasn't already scared of regex.. this just make it worse lol :) as in this case I do not need the objects returned only a single array of name, this does however again offer me a way to play with data that I might not have thought of at this time.  I'm only about 3 months into my PS learning :)  Thanks

Comment: A great resource for testing your regex is regex101.com. While almost all of it translates well into powershell just be aware that some doesn't. Look to SO for any regex help you need!